# .EAR deploying order wildfly-8.0.0Final

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, wildfly

We are having dependencies problem when we try to deploy our .EAR file (wildfly-8.0.0Final).
Below you can find details of the structure of the .EAR, application.xml & standalone.xml files.

Despite setting **initialize-in-order** to TRUE it doesn't seem to follow the order, causing the dependencies problem. We have tried with **ear-subdeployments-isolated** set to both true and false.

Any ideas on how to control the order or any other suggestions?

We found some posts (i.e. using strict) but looks like it was for older versions (JBOSS 4.0).

THANKS MILLION FOR THE HELP!

+mmm-app.ear
 
      |------------ lib (commons-lib)
      |------------ infraestrutura-core.jar (ejb)
      |------------ mmm-logistica.jar (ejb)
      |------------ mmm-admin-core.jar (ejb)
      |------------ mmm-financeiro-core.jar (ejb)
      |------------ mmm-mobile-core.jar (ejb)
      |------------ file1.war
      |------------- file2.war
      |-------------- file3.war
      |--------------- file4.war

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="7" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd">
<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>

<display-name>mmm-package-app</display-name>

<!--A ordem correta de deployment deve ser a desse arquivo, mas com o attributo true ou false não funciona -->

<description>The MMM Deployment Application</description>

<module>
    <ejb>infraestrutura-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
</module>

<module>
    <ejb>mmm-logistica-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
</module>

<module>
    <ejb>mmm-financeiro-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
</module>

<module>
    <ejb>mmm-admin-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
</module>


<module>
    <ejb>mmm-mobile-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
</module>


<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>mmm-admin-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/admin</context-root>
    </web>
</module>


 <module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>mmm-site-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/beta</context-root>
    </web>
</module>


<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>mmm-mobile-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/mobile</context-root>
    </web>
</module>



<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>mmm-lp-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
</module>

<library-directory>lib</library-directory>
```

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>FALSE</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
<spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
<jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
<annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
<concurrent>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
 <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
 <deployment>
  <dependencies>
   <module name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" />
  </dependencies>
 </deployment>
 <sub-deployment name="MMM-admin-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
  <dependencies>
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.infraestrutura-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.MMM-logistica-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.MMM-financeiro-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
  </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
 <sub-deployment name="MMM-site-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
  <dependencies>
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.infraestrutura-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.MMM-logistica-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
  </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
 <sub-deployment name="MMM-mobile-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
  <dependencies>
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.infraestrutura-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.MMM-mobile-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
  </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
 <sub-deployment name="MMM-lp-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
  <dependencies>
   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.infraestrutura-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />

   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.MMM-logistica-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />

   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.MMM-admin-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />

   <module
    name="deployment.MMM-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.MMM-lp-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
  </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Can you please post server logs when you deploy the archive.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly is the problem? Is there a stack trace or anything similar? If you want to ensure that the jars and wars of your ear are loaded in a special order, you could try to add explicite dependencies from one jar to each other, ...

But then the question is why this special order is required.

Comment: Shi thx for ur comment. WARfile1 has dependencies on WARfile0. so if WARfile1 is deployed first, we get errors. It was my understanding that explicit module dependencies should be usd in case of ear-subdeployments-isolated = TRUE no? We have it on FALSE

Comment: Sure, if you set the isolation level to false for subdeployments, then you won't need the dependency to other subdeployments of the same ear in order to use it. But I think there is no guarantee that EAR1 loads after EAR0 in that case since JBoss does not byte code/call stack analysis to determine the correct order. But nevertheless, this is strange behavior. Please post the log for further analysis.

Comment: We are trying to deploy 1 EAR file only. The isolation is set to false, but we are still getting the error. The problem is the .EAR file wildfly deployment sometimes is successfull and sometimes not, the server simply doesn't finish the deployment process. The log is enabled for debug of packages levels but doesn't show any errors.

I don't know the exact cause but it occurs because ejbs jars and wars files are not loaded in order into ear. I have two server.log files. The first log file for when the deployment occurs successfuly and the second for when it fails. any thoughts?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem. I think you cannot count on the exact order in which the jars and wars are loaded from the ear. That's why I proposed to add dependencies between the subdeployments where it is absolutely necessary. I will post this as an answer again so that everyone can find it more easily ;)

Comment: We have also tried that. I just edited my question and added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml. I know this we are moving out of the question here, but could it be a low number of threads on the server? :(

Comment: If you want to ensure that the subdeployments of your ear are loaded in a special order you will need to add dependencies between these subeployments. Your jboss-deployment-structure.xml contains dependencies to other jars, that might exist in another ear since this one contains no more subdeployments. Try adding dependencies within the same ear, like "MMM-admin-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" -> "MMM-site-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" to ensure this deployment order.

what does JBoss say when stopping deployment?

Answer (score 0):

As already posted in the comment above:

Try adding dependencies between the individual subdeployments that have only implicit dependencies. I think this will result in a deterministic loading order on which you can rely.

Comment: How can I set explicit dependencies between subdeployments?